# Tiled Map Editor: Make isometric tiles connect seamlessly/remove staircase effect

Tags: tile, isometric, tiled

I am using the TiledMap editor, with a set of Tiles I got from opengameart,

I am using an isometric map, yet I just can't get these tiles to connect without this "stair-stepped" effect.

[image: Example]

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Map Properties]

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but have you tried different values for stagger axis and or index?

Comment: @EvanCarslake Yes, But no relevant results

Comment: What library/framework is this? Please add tags.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I'm unsure what you mean, but this is what I'm using http://www.mapeditor.org/

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747420/tiled-map-editor-size-of-isometric-tile-side may help.

Comment: Reduce the tile height, that should probably fix it. As in, the value 65 visible in your screenshot.

Comment: Note that in such cases it is helpful to turn on the grid in `View -> Show Grid`, then the cause of the problem may have been easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor "blindly" renders rows of tile-images, These rows are too far apart, leading to this staircase effect. Reduce the map tile height (65 in your screenshot) so that it fits.